# BestPractice использования JNI на Android

Tags: android, jni, best-practice

Необходимо включить в проект `*.so` файлы, которые предварительно генерируются из исходников. Вопрос в следующем:

Следует ли хранить сгенерированные `*.so` файлы в проекте (в папке `libs`, например), или как-то компилировать при запуске приложения? Или добавлять какой-то таргет в gradle? Или писать скрипт для генерирования из исходников?

Ну и главный вопрос - какой из этих путей будет наилучшим? Или есть какие-то ещё варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что то что я использую является каким-то *best practice*, но схема выдержала несколько лет и продолжаю использовать ее по сей день.

1) gradle, равно как и Android Studio хреново работают оба с JNI - это постулат, последний раз я пробовал полгода назад - все равно не работает. В последних версиях gradle/Android Studio постоянно вижу, что *вот теперь наконец улучшена поддержка JNI*, времени проверить еще не было.

2) Конечно же `*.so` файлы надо хранить в каталоге `libs`, смысл в том, что генерация `*.so` файлов процесс небыстрый и нечастый, так что каждый раз генерировать их заново удовольствие ниже среднего.

3) Собственно для самой генерации `*.so` библиотек можно использовать штатный скрипт сборки NDK: `ndk-build.cmd` напрямую из консоли/терминала, но я обычно использую ant скрипт `build-ndk.xml` типа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="my_jni">
   <property file="ndk.properties"/>
   <target name="buildJni">
       <exec failonerror="true" executable="${ndk.dir}/${ndk.build}"/>
   </target>
   <target name="cleanJni">
      <exec failonerror="true" executable="${ndk.dir}/${ndk.build}">
          <arg value="APP_ABI=all"/>
          <arg value="clean"/>
      </exec>
   </target>
</project>
```

Где `ndk.properties` содержит в себе 2 переменных `ndk.dir` и `ndk.build` - место где лежит NDK и название платформенно-зависимого скрипта `ndk-build` сборщика NDK

Для полноты картины этот скрипт можно импортировать в gradle:

```
ant.importBuild "src/main/jni/build-ndk.xml"
```

тогда в списке тасков gradle появятся 2 новых таргета: `buildJni` и `cleanJni`, которые спокойно можно запускать из gradle. Если сильно нужно антовский импорт можно обложить зависимостями, тогда `buildJni` будет запускаться автоматом при изменении сишных исходников.

Предварительно надо "заглушить" попытки поддержки `jni/ndk` в gradle и указать место где будут лежать `*.so` библиотеки:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs=[] //disable ndk support
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs/' //jni libraries
    }
}
```

Как то так.

Comment: Дело в том, что .so генерируются c помощью autogen. Если быть точным - генерится всё следуя [этой](http://zeromq.org/build:android) инструкции с поправками на [эту](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq) редму (она актуальнее банально)

Comment: А что это меняет собственно говоря? Импортируйте в свои исходники все дерево [zeromq](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq) и все

Comment: Я в таком случае не совсем понимаю, как и в какой момент будет происходить компиляция `.so` файлов

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос - как собирать `*.so` файлы из сишных исходников - я то думал, что вы это знаете, раз задаете такие вопросы :)

Comment: Ну вопрос вообще скорее о том, как делают обычно и что делать лучше касательно `*.so` файлов:)

Comment: Обычно берут готовые `*.so`  и вставляют их в свой проект